# K mutually exclusive routes in a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Input: Graph G (assume all edges have unit weights), source-destination vertex pairs (X1, Y1) , (X2 Y2) , ..., (Xk, Yk) (all of them are distinct).

Output: Routes R1 (from X1 to Y1), R2(from X2 to Y2), ... , Rk (from Xk to Yk) such that R1, R2, ..., Rk do not share any vertices between them. No need to optimize the route length.

What algorithm to use? What would be the complexity of this problem? I need a theoretically strong solution, not a heuristics works-most-of-the-time solution.

The most obvious solution is to assign each free vertex(not in X1, X2, .. Xk, or Y1, Y2, ..., Yk) to one of the k paths and see if they actually form paths in the required way. There are possible n^k assignments ( (n-2k)^k to be more precise). Can we do better? What if we assume the graph to be a 2d grid structure? (Equivalent to solving https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bigduckgames.flow  game, but without fill every square requirement).

Comment: Not every graph has such a solution. Take a quincunx graph, where the four endpoint vertices each have only one edge to a single common vertex. Every path must go through the central vertex, which cannot be shared. I would have to say that a correct algorithm must also be able to say that no solution exists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can find one of the possible solutions in this paper: ["The disjoint paths problem in quadratic time" by Ken-ichi Kawarabayashi, Yusuke Kobayashi, Bruce Reed](http://research.nii.ac.jp/~k_keniti/quaddp1.pdf) (pdf).

This solution is not trivial but efficient - only O(N<sup>2</sup>) time complexity, where N is the number of vertices. It is efficient only if K is a small constant.

---

It is also possible to solve this as [Multi-commodity flow problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-commodity_flow_problem). But I doubt any multi-commodity-specific algorithm is efficient enough. Because general multi-commodity flow problem (when flow for at least one commodity is greater than one) is NP-hard.

It is unlikely that this is solvable as a single-commodity flow problem. For example, here is a counter-example to the following proposal:

> ...limiting the S to X2 and T to Y2 edges to capacity 0.5? If there is a pair of disjoint routes with the required match-up, then it is possible to have a total flow of 1.5 from S to T... I am sure this method will give an accurate report of whether there is a set of disjoint paths.

[image: counter-example graph]

It is easy to find a flow of capacity 1.5 (this flow is shown on diagram). But there is no way to connect both (green and red) pairs of vertices with disjoint paths.

Comment: The paper you mention is very useful. The last part of that is unanswered is what is the complexity with respect to K. And can you reduce a canonical problem (eg. any NP complete if this is indeed NP complete with respect to K) into this problem.

Comment: Your counterexample for max flow is very helpful, thanks. (It corresponds to an input consisting of a single edge and *2* source+destination pairs, one going in each direction across it, which obviously can't have a solution.)

Comment: @ElKamina: read introduction to the same paper: `If k is as a part of the input of the problem, then this is one of Karp's original NP-complete problems, and it remains NP-complete even
if G is constrained to be planar`. However it doesn't say anything about 2d grid graphs. This paper doesn't say which exactly Karp's problem is this, but you can find reduction from 3-SAT [here](http://www.shannarasite.org/kb/kbse48.html).

Answer (score 6):

You can use MaxFlow to solve this problem.
If you don't familiar with Flow, you can read some material about it.

### Algorithm

1. Make one super sink vertice S and one super target vertice T. link
   some new edges **S -> X1, S -> X2, Y1 -> T, Y2 -> T....., S -> Xk, Yk -> T**, and set the capacity of each pair of edges 1, 0.75, 0.5 .....
2. Seperate each vertice **p** into two new vertices **p'** and **p"**,
   linked the **p'** and **p"** with a new edge whose capacity is also
   1.
3. Run MaxFlow from S to T, and save the information of the flow-path.
   It' obviously that the maxflow of this new graph is 2. And the two
   flow-path is indicating the required route. Because the algorithm always find the max flow, so the final flow path must be X1 -> Y1, X2 -> Y2 ... Xk -> Yk.

### Proof

Because we seperate each vertice and replaced by one edge whose capacity is 1, so each vertice in the original graph can be traversal by one flow. In other word, it also means each vertice can belong to one path.

### Extend

If you want to minimize the total length of two paths, you can just extend the algorithm. Add each edge in the new graph one property: cost. The cost for the edges from origin graph will be 0; and the cost for that new edges indicating the seperate vertices will be 1.
You can run Min-Cost-Max-Flow algorithm, and get the required information.

### Complexity

The complexity of the MaxFlow is O(N * N * M) by using Dinic algorithm.
And the complexity of Min-Cost-Max-Flow is also approximately O(N * N * N).

Comment: If vertex V has edges to X, Y, and Z, and you split V into V' and V'', which vertices are connected to V' and which are connected to V''?

Comment: @RunningWild If the graph is directional,  for one edge <u, v> in the original graph, the corresponding in the new graph is <u", v'>, ; otherwise, is <u", v'>, <v", u'>

Comment: Why do you think this algorithm produces correct routes X1 to Y1 and X2 to Y2, but not X1-Y2 and X2-Y1 instead?

Comment: @EvgenyKluev Ahhh.... Yes, I ignore some important things. But this trick is easy to solved. If we found a solution that X1 -> Y2, X2 -> Y1, we can find a, b in the path X1 -> Y2, and c, d in the path X2 -> Y1, which satisfied a can reach c and b can reach d. Then we can change our solution into X1 -> a -> c -> Y1 and X2 -> b -> d -> Y1. This step can be done in complexity O(N ^ 4)

Comment: @JunHU  Very innovative solution! I am still not sure if it addresses Evegeny's concern though. I will follow up later today.

Comment: @ElKamina Sorry, after deep thinking, I found that this algorithm would fail to find the answer while the answer existed. That is to say, the algorithm can only find the solution in certain probability. But If you are familiar with NetFlow, you can change the MaxFlow a bit, so that the flow is always from X1 to Y1, X2 to Y2. I hope you can achieve it successfully...

Comment: @JunHU Good answer nevertheless. I will upvote it, but will not accept it.

Comment: Could this be modified by limiting the S to X2 and T to Y2 edges to capacity 0.5? If there is a pair of disjoint routes with the required match-up, then it is possible to have a total flow of 1.5 from S to T. A cross-over X1-Y2, X2-Y1 flow would be at most 1, because each path would use a 0.5 capacity edge.

Comment: I thought I could make it work for more than 2 flows, but now I don't think so.

Comment: And now I think I can get it to work for any k. The issue is making sure that the sum of any group of x initial edge capacities is greater than x-1, so that paths can never be combined. For k=3, we could use 1, 0.75, and 0.5. Any two sum to more than 1, and the three flows sum to 2.25.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Good idea!! I think it's a correct method to solve the trick...

Comment: @ElKamina I have modified the algorithm a bit to satisfied your request, I think my algorithm is effective now.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the way capacities are assigned yet -- could you (or @PatriciaShanahan) explain further please? Thanks!

Comment: I think it may be simpler if we drop using exactly 1, though it is a permitted value. Give the S to Xi and T to Yi edges capacity 1-(1/2)^i. That is, the source and sink edge capacities are 1/2, 3/4, 7/8, 15/16, ...., 1-(1/2)^k. All edges not involving S or T still have capacity 1. If we add up all k special capacities we get k-(1/2)^k which is always greater than k-1.

Comment: I am sure this method will give an accurate report of whether there is a set of disjoint paths. I am not sure whether a typical maximum flow algorithm will share paths given the fractional capacities. For example, an algorithm might send the X1->Y1 flow and 0.5 units of the X2->Y2 flow along the same edge, and the remaining 0.25 units of X2->Y2 along a different edge.

Comment: Thanks @PatriciaShanahan, I see now: if max flow finds a solution that gives full flow for some subset of x pairs, and the sum of the corresponding subset of x special capacities is > x-1, then the minimum cut must have size > x-1; and since all internal edges have capacity 1, this means there must be at least x edge-disjoint source-to-sink paths. Your 1-(1/2)^i capacity scheme works, since the lightest possible size-x subset of them consists of the first x, which sum to x-1+(1/2)^x > x-1.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: I don't think this can be fixed with different source/sink edge capacities. See counter-example in my answer.

Comment: @EvgenyKluev I'm afraid you are right. I withdraw my suggestion. Thanks for your very informative answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a full solution, but I do have a reduction that can be used as a first step. First, decompose the graph into its [biconnected components](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component). This decomposition identifies all the cut vertices, a vertices that, if removed, disconnects the graph into two components. For each cut vertex, the source and destination vertex pairs are either on the same side of the cut, as a non-split pair, or on opposite sides of the cut, as a split pairs. (If the cut vertex is also either source or target, count it as a split pair.)

- If there are two or more split pairs for any cut vertex, the problem has no solution, because both paths would have to pass through the cut vertex. (This is a generalization of the quincunx graph example in my comment above.)
- If there are no split pairs, then the problem resolves into two smaller problems, one on each of the components. The solution is the combination of a solution on each of the smaller ones.
- If there is exactly one split pair, then you reduce the problem to pair of smaller problems, one on a related version of each of the components, where the cut vertex is duplicated between the graphs. Suppose the cut vertex is `X_1` in some component; in that component label the duplicated cut vertex `Y_1`. Vice-versa for the other component. As before, the solution is a combination of that of the two smaller ones.

The essence of this solution is the pigeonhole principle, since two paths can't go through one point. Moving up one step, three points can't go through two points. This leads immediately to examining triconnected components and using [SPQR trees](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPQR_tree). From this structure, you can enumerate all two-point cuts. As before divide, the vertices into two sets and proceed analogously, except that you have to consider all permutations of the split pairs. The subproblems are now all on triconnected components.

You can see where this leads. I don't know if SPQR trees have been generalized to higher degrees of connectivity. Even if they have been, you can expect combinatorial explosion in general. And all this leads to a hard problem.

---

At first, I suspected the problem was tractable on planar graphs. It's not; see the paper referenced above. It remains NP-complete.

Given the above algorithm, you can assume a problem on a biconnected graph. The difference here is that planar graphs only have "local" edges (seen by embedding the graph on a sphere); "remote" edges would have to cross others. That means that behavior of minimal cut sets is much more well behaved. But not enough more well behaved to make the problem work.

Comment: "If there are two or more split pairs for any cut vertex, the problem has no solution, because both paths would have to pass through the cut vertex" -- I think this is wrong.  If a biconnected component has k > 1 cut points, then the component as a whole can support up to k split pairs (assuming the other biconnected components are nice).

Comment: @j_random_hacker: If a graph is biconnected, then `k=0`, because you need to remove at least two vertices to cut the graph. If a graph has `k` different cut vertices, there are `k` different ways to cut the graph into two components with a single vertex removal.

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. I was somehow thinking that if a source-destination pair straddles a cut vertex then it may be possible to "go around the back way" to connect them -- but of course that's *exactly what you can never do* for a cut vertex!

Comment: Some pairs may be separated by more than 1 cut vertex, which may make it easier to prove impossibility of an instance without needing SPQR trees.